# How make mail sending on Hetzner VPS (VQ)?

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, vps

I've changed my hosting to Hetzner VPS (VQ12) with Ubuntu. But mail is not sending from php using mail(); 
I made sendmail intallation:
apt-get install sendmail
sendmailconfig

But after this I receiving 504 timeout error trying mail() function.

cat /var/log/mail.err gives me:
 unable to qualify my own domain name (antonsk) -- using short name
Jan 22 16:00:01 antonsk sm-msp-queue[3513]: My unqualified host name (antonsk) unknown; sleeping for retry

What should I do with this to make it work?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your host FQDN name (FQDN = Fully Qualified Domain Name)

[How to set the fully qualified domain name in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158957/how-to-set-the-fully-qualified-domain-name-in-12-0)

Comment: Where could I obtain it?

Comment: You may use free DNS domain (e.g. provided by freedns.afraid.org, www.noip.com) during start/test period and buy your own DNS domain later.